# Momentum and CM of a continuous object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames

It's easy to prove
$$ \vec{P} = M \dot{\vec{R}}_{cm}\tag{1}$$
in the discrete case. Total momentum $\vec{P}$ is defined as a discrete sum of all the little momenta $\Sigma \vec{p}$. The center of mass $\vec{R}_{cm} = \Sigma m_n \vec{r}_n / M$. Assuming $m_n$ and $M$ are constant, then derivatives are nice and easy and we get the above result.

For a continuous object, 
$$\vec{R}_{cm} = \frac{1}{M}\int dm\;\vec{r} = \frac{1}{M}\int \rho\; \vec{r}\; dV$$
Does equation $(1)$ still hold for a continuous object? You would think 
$$ \dot{\vec{R}}_{cm} = \frac{1}{M}\int dm \;\vec{v}$$

However, shouldn't we allow $dm$ to change with time? $\vec{r}$ points to and follows a $dm$. But couldn't the density $\rho$ change with time and therefore change $dm$? In other words, some of the mass in this $dm$ goes into the mass of another $dm$. Or maybe a $dm$ deforms and therefore it's the volume we have to worry about over time?

**Related question**:
Does $\vec{F} = M\ddot{\vec{R}}_{cm}$ still hold for a continuous object? It's easy to prove for the discrete case. But for the continuous case, I run into the problem of the derivative again.

Comment: Here, you highlight the difference between rigid bodies and non-rigid bodies. In rigid bodies, the density is not allowed to change as a function of body coordinates, so you don't run into these problems. Most classical mechanics courses only study rigid bodies in any sort of moving context. Non-rigid bodies are usually taken to be stationary. More directly addressing the problem at hand, let me ask you this: what is causing the density to change? Doesn't a change in density usually correspond to the application of some sort of stress (i.e. force)?

Comment: The question came up because my book started talking about momentum conservation and rockets (steady mass loss over time due to fuel ejection). I thought this was odd because we suddenly started talking about a continuous mass distribution as opposed to an N-particle system. So I became curious about which equations still work in the continuous case. But thinking about what you said, the density could only change given some applied force (as a function of position over the body and time). I was thinking about a fluid-like blob twisting and deforming on it's own. But I guess that could only

Comment: A fluid twisting and deforming on its own has a bunch of internal stresses that cause it to behave as it does.

Comment: happen if there was some internal force field within the body (a function of location over the body and time). Interesting, then we could think about ruptures and holes forming. But this is starting to sound complicated. So I don't know what my question is anymore. But is there some general mathematics that you know of behind time derivatives of volume integrals? Or even time derivatives of line/surface integrals? And do you know of anything about the center-of-mass and momentum connection in this non-rigid case? I guess that's my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the body we're studying has a finite volume. For a continuous, non-rigid body, we can only specify two things in general: its density field $\rho(\vec{r},t)$ and the particular region of space it occupies $U(t)$. The center of mass is then given by

$$\vec{R}=\frac{1}{M}\int_{U(t)}\rho\vec{r}dV$$

The behavior of the time derivative of an integral of a time-dependent vector field over a time-dependent region is given by the Reynolds Transport Theorem (which is in reality a special case of the Leibniz integral rule). Let $\vec{f}(\vec{r},t)=\rho(\vec{r},t)\vec{r}$. Then the Reynolds Transport Theorem reads:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{U(t)}\vec{f}dV=\int_{U(t)}\frac{\partial\vec{f}}{\partial t}dV+\int_{\partial U(t)}(\vec{v_b}\cdot\vec{n})\vec{f}dA$$

where $\partial U(t)$ is the boundary of the body, $\vec{n}$ is the outward normal, and $\vec{v_b}$ is the boundary velocity. Substituting the relevant physical quantities:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{R}=\int_{U(t)}\left(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\vec{r}+\rho\vec{v}\right)dV+\int_{\partial U(t)}(\vec{v_b}\cdot \vec{n})\rho\vec{r}dA$$

At this point, the calculation becomes quite situation-dependent, as the behavior of $U(t)$, $\partial U(t)$, and $\rho$ all depend on the particular physics you're considering. Note that if $\rho$ is constant and $\vec{v_b}\cdot\vec{n}$ is zero, it reduces to $\int dm\;\vec{v}$.